# parking ticket sim having output issue

Tags: java

Truthfully, I mixed some codes.

I need output like below:

```
Parking ticket #:
Fined amount:
Car issued to:
Issued by officer:
```

But here is current output:

```
Fined amount:  
Car issued to:  
Parking ticket #:null 
Fined amount: 
Issued by officer:
```

So looks like the main issue is with generating a parking ticket #

Code is

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ParkingTicketSimulator
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        String make, model, color, license, name, badge;
        int parkedMinutes, meterMinutes;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("=== Parking Ticket Simulator ===\n\n");
        System.out.print("---------\n");
        System.out.print("Car Data\n");
        System.out.print("---------\n\n");
    System.out.print("Enter the car make: ");
    make = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the car model: ");
    model = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the car color: ");
    color = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the car license number: ");
    license = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter minutes car has been parked:");
    parkedMinutes = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\n----------\n");
    System.out.print("Meter Data\n");
    System.out.print("----------\n\n");

    System.out.print("Enter minutes purchased by driver:");
    meterMinutes = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\n-------\n");
    System.out.print("PO Data\n");
    System.out.print("-------\n\n");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter police officer's name:");
    name = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter police officer's badge number:");
    badge = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\n---------------------\n");
    System.out.print("Parking Ticket Issued\n");
    System.out.print("---------------------\n\n");

    ParkedCar car = new ParkedCar(make,model,color,license,parkedMinutes);
    ParkingMeter meter1 = new ParkingMeter (meterMinutes);
    PoliceOfficer officer1 = new PoliceOfficer(name,badge,car,meter1);

    System.out.println(officer1.getExpired(officer1));


     }
```

```
      public static class ParkedCar {

      private String make;
      private String model;
      private String color;
      private String license;
      private int minutesParked;

      public ParkedCar() {
        make = "";
        model = "";
        color = "";
        license = "";
        minutesParked = 0;
      }

      public ParkedCar(ParkedCar carDetails){
        make = carDetails.make;
        model = carDetails.model;
        color = carDetails.color;
        license = carDetails.license;
        minutesParked = carDetails.minutesParked;
      }

      public ParkedCar(String make, String model, String color, String license, int minutesParked){
      this.make = make;
      this.model = model;
      this.color = color;
      this.license = license;
      this.minutesParked = minutesParked;
      }

      public void setMake (String make){
      this.make = make;
      }
      public void setModel (String model){
        this.model = model;
      }
      public void setColor (String color){
        this.color = color;
      }
      public void setLicense (String license){
        this.license = license;
      }
      public void minutesParked (int minutesParked){
        this.minutesParked = minutesParked;
      }

      public String getMake(){
        return make;
      }
      public String getModel(){
        return model;
      }
      public String getColor(){
        return color;
      }
      public String getLicense(){
        return license;
      }
      public int getMinutesParked(){
        return minutesParked;
      }

      public String toString(){
        String str = "\nMake: " + make + "\nModel: " + model + "\nColor: " + color + "\nLicense: " + license + "\nMinutes parked: " + minutesParked;
        return str;
      }

    }
```

```
    public static class ParkingMeter {
      private int minutes;

      public ParkingMeter() {
        minutes = 0;
      }

      public ParkingMeter(int minutes){
        this.minutes = minutes;
      }

      public ParkingMeter (ParkingMeter minutesDetail){
        minutes = minutesDetail.minutes;
      }

    public void setMinutes (int minutes){
      this.minutes = minutes;
      }

      public int getMinutes(){
        return minutes;
      }

      public String toString(){
      String str ="\nMinutes: " + minutes;
      return str;
      }

    }
```

```
    public static class ParkingTicket{
        private PoliceOfficer officer; //Calls the officer details.
        private ParkedCar car;
        private ParkingMeter meter;
        private int fees;

      public ParkingTicket(PoliceOfficer officer){
        this.officer = new PoliceOfficer(officer);
        this.meter = officer.getMeter();
        this.car = officer.getParkedCar();
        }

        public ParkingTicket(){

        }

      public int fees(){

        int time;

        if (car != null || meter != null){
        time = car.getMinutesParked() - meter.getMinutes() - 1;
        fees = 25;
        while (time > 0){
          time = time - 1;
          fees = fees+10;
        }
        }
        return fees;
      }

      public String toString(){
        if (fees() == 0 ){
          String str = "There is no ticket issued.";
           return str;
        }
        else{
        String str = "\n" + officer +"\nTime over: "  + (car.getMinutesParked() - meter.getMinutes()) + "\nThe fee is $" + fees();
        return str;
      }
      }
    }
```

```
    public  static class PoliceOfficer{
      private String name;
      private String badge;
      private ParkedCar car;
      private ParkingMeter meter;
      private ParkingTicket ticket;

        public PoliceOfficer(String name, String badge, ParkedCar carDetails, ParkingMeter time) {
          this.name = name;
          this.badge = badge;
          car = new ParkedCar(carDetails);
          meter = new ParkingMeter(time);
        }

      public PoliceOfficer(PoliceOfficer officerDetails){
        name = officerDetails.name;
        badge = officerDetails.badge;
        car = officerDetails.car;
        meter = officerDetails.meter;
      }

      public void setName (String name){
      this.name = name;
      }

      public void setBadge (String badge){
        this.badge = badge;
      }

      public String getName(){
        return name;
      }
      public String getBadge(){
        return badge;
      }

      public ParkedCar getParkedCar() {
           return new ParkedCar(car);
        }

      public ParkingMeter getMeter(){
        return new ParkingMeter(meter);
      }

      public ParkingTicket getExpired(PoliceOfficer officer){
        if (meter.getMinutes() - car.getMinutesParked() < 0){
        ticket = new ParkingTicket(officer);
        return ticket;
        }
        else 

        ticket = new ParkingTicket();
        return ticket;
      }

      public String toString(){
        String str = "Officer Details\nOfficer's Name: " + name + "\nOfficer's Badge Number: " + badge + "\n\nCar Information: " + car + "\n\nMeter Information: " + meter;
        return str;
      }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you follow every `keyboard.nextInt()` with `keyboard.nextLine()`; input of `meterMinutes` has it, but input of `parkedMinutes` doesn't.

Comment: format question and separate classes

Comment: I just tried to compile it, and I'm getting lots of `error: modifier static not allowed here` Is that because they were all inner classes? And you were told to separate them out?

Comment: This is not the same code that is generating the output you've shown.

Comment: yeah originally it was combined because thats how the compiler works as one code instead of separate. but its separate here for reading